# Django + NGINX https redirect (414 Request-URI Too Large)

Tags: nginx, https, redirect, django

I am trying to solve nginx redirect to https but when I use www.ozkandurakoglu.com I am getting 414 Request-URI Too Large error. Here is my settings for nginx:

```
upstream ozkan_server {
  server unix:/home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name ozkandurakoglu.com www.ozkandurakoglu.com;
    return 301 $scheme:https://ozkandurakoglu.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/chain.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  server_name www.ozkandurakoglu.com;
  return 301 $scheme:https://ozkandurakoglu.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/chain.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  server_name  www.ozkandurakoglu.com ozkandurakoglu.com;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  root /home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/;
  access_log /home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/logs/nginx-access.log;
  error_log /home/ytsejam/public_html/ozkansimple/logs/nginx-error.log warn;
  large_client_header_buffers 6 16k;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `server` block twice for `https://www.ozkandurakoglu.com`.

If you want `https://ozkandurakoglu.com` to redirect to `https://www. ozkandurakoglu.com`, you need to leave one block for `https://www. ozkandurakoglu.com` which hosts the actual site, and then have this block for redirect:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ozkandurakoglu.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ozkandurakoglu.com/chain.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    return 301 https://www.ozkandurakoglu.com$request_uri;
}
```